# Simulation "zelig style" for GLMER multilevel in r

Tags: r, simulation, lme4, r-zelig, multilevel-analysis

I run a logistic mixed-effects regression with r. The regression is somehow like this:

glmer ( Y~ X1 + X2 + X1:X2 + (1 | country), data = hdp, family = binomial)

Now, with the fixed effects I would like to plot predicted probabilities of Y. I tried with Zelig as this is what I learnt as the easiest way to do simulations and get predicted probabilities, but I've seen the new version does not include multilevel models and the former Zelig Multilevel is very "unstable". Is there any easy alternative? How can I do simulations that could be plotted??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `simulate(model, newdata = hdp[, -1])` or `predict`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [merTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/index.html) package.